# Call to undefined function array_keys()

Tags: arrays, php-7

I get this error an i am using php7 .
According to the manual it is in php 7 . What can i be doing wrong if the function is native to php why i still get the error.

```
fputcsv($fp,‌‌array_keys($results[0][0]));
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ‌‌array_keys()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `array_keys()` call is preceded by two `U+200C` (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER) characters which is being interpreted as part of the function name.

Was the function name copied/pasted from the internet somewhere?

Comment: Delete the comma and the `a` after `$fp` and retype them manually. That should fix your issue.